# prepending images in specific order

Tags: jquery, prepend

I know this isn't the best way to do this, but unfortunately due to a deadline this is what it is.  I have three images I'm loading and then prepending into a div, I'd like them to be prepended in a specific order.  Right now this is what I have but I'm unsure how to prepend in the order.  I don't want to use jquery load either.  The images are listed in the order I'd like them to be in, I was thinking just writing it so one function doesn't start until the next is finished?  But I wasn't sure how to do that either.  Thanks for any help on this.

```
$("#pt_figures").click(function() {
$("<img>", { src: "http://www.klossal.com/figures_doc.png" }).prependTo("#images"); 
$("<img>", { src: "http://www.klossal.com/figure_front.png" }).prependTo("#images"); 
$("<img>", { src: "http://www.klossal.com/figure_back.png" }).prependTo("#images");
});
```

Comment: that makes sense, I'll work on this.  I'd still appreciate any help on this question!

Comment: Why doesn't what you currently have work at the moment? What's it producing?

Comment: http://www.klossal.com/ click the bottom image of the figures.  It loads them just not in the correct order.  It loads them back first, then front then doc.  Seems to add them in the order it finishes loading the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is simple.

Use `.append()` not `.prepend()`

```
$("#pt_figures").click(function() {
  $("<img>", { src: "http://www.klossal.com/figures_doc.png" }).appendTo("#images"); 
  $("<img>", { src: "http://www.klossal.com/figure_front.png" }).appendTo("#images"); 
  $("<img>", { src: "http://www.klossal.com/figure_back.png" }).appendTo("#images");
});
```

People tend to overlook simple things when on tight deadlines - easy mistake to make.

Comment: hahaha, thanks for that.  Another set of eyes is always helpful, thanks :)